# what does "displayArea" and "provider" of checkout_index_index.xml mean in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

[image]

what does `displayArea` and `provider` of `checkout_index_index.xml` mean in magento2?

Answer (score 34):

To understand what `checkoutProvider` and `displayArea` are, you must first understand the scope you are looking in: `jsLayout`.

`jsLayout` is a bunch of JavaScript configuration for the JavaScript UI elements on the checkout page. If you look at `module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`, you'll notice the following `x-magento-init`-data:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkout": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is where it all starts. It states:

> For element `#checkout`, initialize the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app`-component with the following information: ...

And the information it receives is the information created in the layout XML: `jsLayout`. Now, this means that **everything** in your XML is now passed through to the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app`-component (leaving plugins, and layout processors and stuff out of the equation for the moment...)

Now, I'm not going to dive into detail into how `module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/app.js` boils everything down, because that would make this post very, very long, but the summary is this:

- The `Magento_Ui/js/core/app`-component creates a `checkout`-component.
- This will be a component of the type `uiComponent` (this is a very generic component that can be used to defer your own custom UI components from. It comes with basic knockout template rendering and stuff).
- It will us the template `Magento_Checkout/web/frontend/template/onepage.html`.
- It will create various children (with the name `errors`, `estimation`, `steps`, etc...)
- The `steps`-child will also be a `uiComponent`.
- This cycle continues... the configuration makes children with various parameters.

Now to get to your `displayArea` and `provider`-question: As you've seen above, everything maps to JavaScrip classes. The first time we see the use of `displayArea` is when we create the `steps`-component, which is of the type `uiComponent`. So `uiComponent` would be a logical candidate to look for the use of `displayArea`.

Now, a `uiComponent` is a JavaScript class of the type `Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection`. (You can look this up in `module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js`). This maps to `module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/collection.js`. Here we see the following use:

```
/**
 * Synchronizes multiple elements arrays with a core '_elems' container.
 * Performs elemets grouping by theirs 'displayArea' property.
 * @private
 *
 * @returns {Collection} Chainable.
 */
_updateCollection: function () {
    var _elems = compact(this._elems),
        grouped;

    grouped = _elems.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.displayArea && _.isString(elem.displayArea);
    });
    grouped = _.groupBy(grouped, 'displayArea');

    _.each(grouped, this.updateRegion, this);

    this.elems(_elems);

    return this;
},
```

So what this does in effect, it 'maps' a uiComponent to a certain group of UI components. This is important to know, because it allows us to move UI components to other locations in the layout, by just manipulating the XML layout, just like you would do this with `phtml` templates that are rendered server-side. Just override the `displayArea`, and you can render any JavaScript UI Component anywhere else (given that the target area is also rendered somewhere).

Now for your second question: `provider`. Just like we've looked up `displayArea`, we should start looking at the UI Component first, which is `Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email`. And if we look at the `requirejs-config.js`, we finally find `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js`.

But ... no `provider` is used in this class. So let's just see if we can find anything in the class it extends: `Component` (which is our `uiComponent`-class again).

But ... no `provider` as well. Well, `uiComponent` simply extends `Element` (which is located at `module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/element.js`), so let's just look over there:

```
/**
 * Parses 'modules' object and creates
 * async wrappers for specified components.
 *
 * @returns {Element} Chainable.
 */
initModules: function () {
    _.each(this.modules, function (name, property) {
        if (name) {
            this[property] = this.requestModule(name);
        }
    }, this);

    if (!_.isFunction(this.source)) {
        this.source = registry.get(this.provider);
    }

    return this;
},
```

Bingo! It turns out that the provider is used as a source to fetch data from. If we look at the constructor of `Element`, you'll see that by default, it's set to empty:

```
provider: '',
```

So back to our configuration. If we now read our configuration, we'll understand that the item `shippingAddress` is a component of `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping`, that fetches it's data from the `checkoutProvider`.

So that leaves us with two questions:

1. Where is `checkoutProvider` defined?
2. How is it used in the shipping JavaScript?

Well, if you'll scroll to the bottom of `checkout_index_index.xml`, you'll notice that it's nothing more than a vanilla `uiComponent`:

```
<item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
</item>
```

And if you look at `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`, you'll see that it is used like this:

```
registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function (checkoutProvider) {
    var shippingAddressData = checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData();

    if (shippingAddressData) {
        checkoutProvider.set(
            'shippingAddress',
            $.extend({}, checkoutProvider.get('shippingAddress'), shippingAddressData)
        );
    }
    checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function (shippingAddressData) {
        checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddressData);
    });
});
```

To be honest: this is where my analyzing stops, because it becomes for me also hard to search and invest what's going on, but I hope someone else can pick it up from here ...

I know it has something to do with the `registry.async()` returning a method that gets immediately executed with a callback function as argument, but someone else needs to explain this...

---

** Disclaimer: By all means, please correct me if I'm wrong! Haven't tried any of the above for real, but I have been working almost for year now with Magento 2 and I believe this is how it works. Unfortunately there isn't much documentation if you want to dive to the bottom of the Magento Ocean.*

Comment: so what is displayArea ?

Comment: This is brilliant analysis, did you ever develop a further understanding?

Answer (score 19):

6 months after my original answer I think I can provide a better answer on what `displayArea` is.

In my understanding, it all comes together with Knockouts' `getTemplate()`-method, the `getRegion()`-method, and children in UI Components. A good example of this can be seen when you're examining `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/registration.phtml` and `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/registration.html`.

In `registration.phtml`, you'll see a default Magento UI Component that has children:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#registration": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "registration": {
                        "component": "Magento_Checkout/js/view/registration",
                        "config": {
                            "registrationUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCreateAccountUrl(); ?>",
                            "email": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getEmailAddress(); ?>"
                        },
                        "children": {
                            "errors": {
                                "component": "Magento_Ui/js/view/messages",
                                "sortOrder": 0,
                                "displayArea": "messages",
                                "config": {
                                    "autoHideTimeOut": -1
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note the use of `displayArea` in the `children`-node. Basically, it tells Knockout that this child element should be rendered in a region called *'messages'*.

Now take a look at the top of `registration.html`:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

What this line of Knockout code basically does, is: it iterates over all child elements that are present in the displayArea *'messages'*, and renders them.

Basically, the naming is a bit confusing if you ask me. Why would you use *'displayArea'* in one place, and *'region'* in another place. But perhaps my assumption is totally incorrect. Perhaps a Magento core developer could shine a bit more light on this?

Comment: This is what's confused me for so long, I keep seeing `getRegion` and my mind just implodes. Thank you for both answers by the way, very helpful!

Comment: Well, this is just my 2 cents. I hope somebody of the core developers can share some light on this topic. The deeper internals of Magento 2, and especially the whole Knockout / XHR implementation are something that has been not so-well documented.

Comment: Agreed, unless you delve into many of the core files there's pretty much no way other than this stack exchange to know what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a step back and try to not specifically understand how this was implemented, but how it is expected to be implemented, I think it's a lot simpler to understand this.

When a UI Component is created, it's placed in sort of a "general" display area. If you wanted to output all UI Components within a specific `jsLayout` node, you would do something like:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

This loops through all UI Component elements, and outputs each of their templates. Easy enough.

Say that instead of outputting all templates, you only want to display a related group of UI Components. This is where regions and display areas come into play.

This is prevalent in some files such as `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`:

```html
...
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('estimation') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
...
```

Let's take a look at this small code block specifically:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

This loops through all UI Components on the page, and only outputs those with that contain a `displayArea` config property that matches the region name. For example, if we open up the related `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file, we will see a block of code like this:

```xml
...
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
    </item>
    ...
```

You'll notice this node has a `displayArea` value assigned to `messages`:

```xml
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
```

This is the field that assigns these UI Component nodes to the regions, which are then outputted within the Knockout template when the following block is called:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Like below code to render all child elements specified for particular node, as it will give extendibility to future layout nodes as well.                                                                                                       <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->